# Change Value of Current Child - SimpleXML PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

The setup is quite simple. How do you use the children() iterating function of SimpleXML and then modify the value of the current node? Here's a scenario below:

```
<Ad>
  <Unit>Value</Unit>
  <Size>Value</Size>
  <Time>Value</Time>
</Ad>
```

I'm trying to use children() and then to assign to the current Child to change "Value" in all of the above nodes.

```
foreach ($parent->children() as $child){
  $child= "New Value"; // Proper way to access $child's value without overwriting the entire object???
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I understand you can simply do the following:

```
$parent->Unit = "New Value";
```

I'm asking specifically in the case of using the children() method, how can you access the value of the current child object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `SimpleXMLElement` represents a single element (rather than a collection of elements with the same name), index `[0]` can be used as a self-reference.

Writing to that self-reference uses the overloaded assignment that you can use in other contexts to set the text content of a node.

So the code you are looking for is as simple as:

```
foreach ($parent->children() as $child) {
    $child[0] = "New Value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For case where you won't know the node names ahead of time you can try:

```
foreach ($parent->children() as $name => $child) {                                                                                                                                               
    $parent->{$name} = 'new value';
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to modify the value of the current child in the iterator. It's a special case because SimpleXML isn't a standard object. The method you've suggested errors out. EDIT: To be more clear, the current Child is also of type SimpleXMLElement, meaning you can't simply assign to it, or it will overwrite the entire object. They don't expose a "set" method, however. Generally, you can do (like I've shown in my question) $parent->NodeName, when you know the node name. However, I'm in a special scenario where I won't know the node names ahead of time.

Comment: @ChrisManning,  I updated code a bit - please have a look. So - is it cover your requirements? You do not know names now. But you can get names in foreach and you can use them to change values of children nodes...